# saving jsp contents as pdf file in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

i am viewing some data from db on a jsp i spring MVC.i need to add a functionality as "save as PDF"
so that we can save output of jsp file into pdf.
how can i achieve this.
plz,,,if some one has code,post it here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC to open PDF as the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951731/spring-mvc-to-open-pdf-as-the-view)

Comment: @nidhi: asking for code is not welcomed here.

Comment: @nidhi: however, for your problem, I think you may try Apache FOP. You can make a frame for your data by xml, then export it to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need this library http://itextpdf.com/ and then set the content type of response.

[Answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959264/106261)

Comment: what all jars i need to include??

Comment: @nidhi all the details are in the link and previous answer, read them.